# Overview maps within atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas

I have been working with the atlas generation option in QGIS for some time and it works great! What I cannot figure out is how to incorporate the overview function into it.

Here is an example of what I want to get. I want to generate an atlas of 10 different UTM grids. One map per grid. On each map I want a zoom-in overview map to the shapefile labeled with numbers on the map.
[image]
However when I move on to the next UTM grid in my atlas generator, the overview is still on the old location. Here I would like an overview map showing number 17 to 19, not 9 and 11, since they are no longer in the scope of this map.
[image]

If I make the overview map to be selected by the atlas I can only have it selected by the same UTM grid I have for my main map, which is off course not very usefull. Any thoughts on how to get this done? Feels like I should be able to do some conditional formatting on the atlas generation level.

Comment: This should be automatic. How do you configure the overview map?

Comment: @Martin F, what do you mean? If I make the overview controlled by the atalas too, I just get the same map twice in one print overview. I am basically looking to have my main map controlled by one shapefile in atlas, and the overview map by another shapefile.

Comment: I think you're addressing @underdark?

Answer (score 4):

So I found a workaround.

1. I creathed a new shapefile of polygons envelopping all of my point locations/small polygons.
2. I drew two maps and made both controlled in atlas by the newly drawn shape
3. I set the scale of one of them to fixed and the other to a certain % around the polygon.

he maps are still centered around the polygons rahter than the UTM grids, but with some smart labeling I managed to make it workable.
[image: image was altered to not give away some info]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a map based on the utm grids you will have to greate a vector storage (shapefile or other) in which every grid (zone) is a separate object. The atlas functionality will not work with points data. Both maps (detail and overview) will have to be controlled by the atlas.

[image]

The only difference is the margin around the feature. You will find the setting under the "Item properties". For a fully fledged example you are advised to take a look at [this github project](https://github.com/ragnvald/qgis_protectedareasmap) where the setup should provide you with a decent point of reference. Note that after syncing the github project you will have to download the most recent overview of protected areas for Tanzania from [this website](http://www.protectedplanet.net/country/TZ).

Answer (score 0):

I did have same kind of problem and i found a solution that worked for me. It offer the possibility to have two map depending on atlas feature but not centered on it (like you want one have to follow a gird).

For one map (the smallest in your case) you use simply the extent control by atlas.
For the second map you set the extent definition (min X, min Y, max X and max Y) depending on attributes of your atlas feature.

You can access any attribute of your atlas feature trough a formula.

For example : `attributes(@atlas_feature) ['x_map_min']`

You just have to choose the best solution to store in each atlas feature the extent definition (by hand or using join and so)